# How do I see hadith ratings/clasfications specifically by Sheikh Al-Albani

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, islamic-scholar

Sunnah.com sometimes will say (Al-Albani) or (Darussalam) how do I find classifications (For hadiths) by specifically Al-Albani? Personally, I want to see his ruling on a hadith in Bukhari.

Answer (score 1):

[Nasiruddin al-Albani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Nasiruddin_al-Albani) has authored various books in which he has discussed and graded various ahadith. These are in Arabic and are available online if you search for them e.g. [here](https://al-maktaba.org/category/131). You would need enough familiarity with Arabic to transverse the books and find the grading.

Comment: Is it public domain?